# java library - remove access to dependency

Tags: java, dependencies, shared-libraries

A java library I am modifying has a third party networking library in it.

Projects that use this library as a dependency also are now able to create objects with that networking library.

Without speculating on the various pros and cons, can I limit or disable access to the networking library contained within my library?

Comment: You would need to repackage it into package-private code that only you can call. Or use OSGi.

Comment: Will doing so impact existing client code?

Comment: @PM77-1 the library hasn't launched yet.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscate the third party networking library before releasing your library.